# Passar variável para dentro do IN

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Estou com dificuldade de passar uma variável para dentro do `IN` no MySQL - PHP - PDO.

Na URL está assim: `/PESO=50&IDADE=18,20`

Código:

```
$read->FullRead("SELECT DISTINCT NOME FROM pessoas WHERE PESO =:peso AND IDADE IN (:idade) AND SEXO =:sexo", 'peso='.$_GET['PESO'].'&idade='.$_GET['IDADE'].'&sexo"=MASCULINO');
```

Comment: O que é `$read`? O que é `FullRead`?

Comment: Qual erro esta dando?

Comment: Tente dar uma olhada no que foi feito neste exemplo do SO em inglês; parece que o PDO não é muito bom para cláusulas IN parametrizadas, na consulta: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14767651/4649737

Comment: $read e meu Objeto e FullRead e o metodo que utilizo deste objeto.